# How to check for custom attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am using a middleware to sanitize asp.net endpoints using HtmlSanitizer as explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5313718/Preventing-XSS-in-NET-Core-Web-APIs?fid=1976534&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=5864886&view=Normal&prof=True&tid=5864846). But its not working for file uploads. So I am trying to use a custom attribute called `XssSanitizeIgnore` as explained in the discussions section.

I create `XssSanitizeIgnore` attribute inside `My controller` as follows,

```
namespace CarPortal.ReportingServiceApi.Controllers.APIControllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AutoReportController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IAutoReportService _autoReportService;
        public AutoReportController(IAutoReportService autoReportService) : base()
        {
            _autoReportService = autoReportService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [XssSanitizeIgnore]
        [Route("ProcessUploadedFile")]
        public async Task<string> ProcessUploadedFile([FromForm] object formData)
        {

            return await _autoReportService.ProcessUploadedFile((IFormFile)formData);
        }

    }
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)]
public class XssSanitizeIgnore: Attribute
{
}
```

but I am not sure how can I use it inside the `middleware`

```
// enable buffering so that the request can be read by the model binders next
            httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

            // leaveOpen: true to leave the stream open after disposing, so it can be read by the model binders
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var raw = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var sanitiser = new HtmlSanitizer();
                var sanitised = sanitiser.Sanitize(raw);

                System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoReportController));
//ignore if XssSanitizeIgnore 
                if (raw != sanitised)
                {
                    throw new BadRequestException("XSS injection detected from middleware.");
                }
            }

            // rewind the stream for the next middleware
            httpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet code to check if this endpoint has an attribute.

```
var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
var myCustomAttribute = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<MyCustomAttribute>();
if (myCustomAttribute is not null)
{
    // ToDo: do someting
}
```

and if possible use this attribute more than once so you can use this instead.

```
var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
var myCustomAttributes = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetOrderedMetadata<MyCustomAttribute>();
if (myCustomAttributes != null && myCustomAttributes.Any())
{
    // ToDo: do someting
}
```